# Why does bash sometime not flush output of a python program to a file

Tags: bash, file, flush

I have a crontab job calling a python script and outputting to a file:

```
python run.py &> current_date.log
```

now sometimes when I do

```
tail -f current_date.log
```

I see the file filling up with the output, but other times the log file exists, but stays empty for a long time. I am sure that the python script is printing stuff right after it starts running, and the log file **is** created. Any ideas why does it stay empty some of the time?

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/python-output-buffering

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Python buffers output when it detects that it is not writing to a tty, and so your log file may not receive any output right away. You can configure your script to flush output or you can invoke python with the `-u` argument to get unbuffered output.

```
$ python -h

...

-u     : unbuffered binary stdout and stderr (also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x)
         see man page for details on internal buffering relating to '-u'

...
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem is actually Python (not bash) and is by design.  Python buffers output by default.  Run python with `-u` to prevent buffering.

Another suggestion is to create a class (or special function) which calls `flush()` right after the write to the log file.